# MVC jqGrid - cannot get cell editing to work "No Url is Set"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am working on a MVC 2 project where I want to use jqGrid where I can edit the cells of a grid.
When I edit a cell and press enter, I get "No Url is Set"
My View looks like;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    JobTitles
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Job Titles Maintenance</legend>
            <table id="list" class="scroll" style="font-size: 11px;"></table>  
            <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;font-size: 11px;"></div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <%--jqGrid Code - refer http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html --%>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { reloadGrid(); });

        function reloadGrid() {
            var $grid = $("#list");
            $grid.jqGrid({
                url: '<%: Url.Action("GetCurrentJobTitles", "Maintenance")%>',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'POST',
                colNames: ['JobTitleId', 'Title', 'Head Office Based', 'Usage'],
                colModel: [
                { name: 'JobTitleId', index: 'JobTitleId', key: true, editable: true, editrules: { readonly: true } },
        { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 280, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true},
        { name: 'HeadOfficeFlag', index: 'HeadOfficeFlag', width: 100, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox' },
        { name: 'Usage', index: 'Usage', width: 40, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: false }],
                cellEdit: true,
                cellSubmit: 'remote',
                cellUrl: '<%: Url.Action("UpdateJobTitle", "Maintenance")%>',
                pager: $('#pager'),
                rowNum: 25,
                rowList: [10, 25, 50, 100, 500],
                sortname: 'Title',
                sortorder: "asc",
                viewrecords: true,
                caption: 'Job Titles',
                height: 575
            });
        }

    </script>  

</asp:Content>
```

My controller looks like;

```
public ActionResult UpdateJobTitle(CellEditingViewModel viewModel)
{
    var jobTitle = JobTitle.GetById(viewModel.JobTitleId);
    switch (viewModel.PropertyName)
    {
        case "Title":
            jobTitle.Title = viewModel.PropertyValue.ToString();
            break;

        case "HeadOfficeFlag":
            jobTitle.HeadOfficeFlag = Convert.ToBoolean(viewModel.PropertyValue);
            break;
    }

    try
    {
        jobTitle.Update();
    }
    catch
    {
        return this.Json(false);
    }

    return this.Json(true);
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that the object posted from jqGrid when you edit and press enter doesn't match the view model that your controller expects. This site has a good example of inline editing with MVC: http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/ASP.NET MVC Examples/jqGrid Examples/jqGrid/ Check out the view models/binder they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use correct case in jqGrid options:

```
cellsubmit: 'remote',
cellurl: '<%: Url.Action("UpdateJobTitle", "Maintenance")%>',
```

but `cellEdit: true`. jqGrid have no clear name conversion for the name of options. :-(

I would recommend you additionally to use `pager: '#pager'` instead of `pager: $('#pager')`, add `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true` options, remove `index` properties from all column definition, remove unneeded `align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: false` properties from `colModel` (see description of default values of `colModel` properties in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options)).

Comment: Thank you for that Oleg. Both you and Darin Dimitrov are my favourite people!

Comment: @arame3333: You are welcome! Thanks to compare me with Darin Dimitrov. :-)